# What is the name for the equation ΔG = ΔG° + RT ln Q?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

As the title states, what is the name of the equation

$$\Delta G=\Delta G^{\circ}+RT \ln Q$$

My textbook does not explicitly state the name and I could not find anything on google.

Comment: I've never heard that this equation has a special name.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no "name" for that specific equation. It's just one (of very many) relations involving [Gibbs free energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy).

Comment: [this](http://www.vias.org/genchem/equilib_2ndlaw_12593_09.html) might help.