# Can ΔG = ΔG° + RT ln Q be used to calculate K at different temperatures?

Tags: equilibrium, free-energy

Specifically, can $\Delta G=\Delta G^{\circ}+RT \ln Q$ be used to calculate reaction quotients if we choose T to be a different temperature than the one provided by ΔG°?

For example, suppose that we are given ΔG° at 25°C and we are tasked with finding the equilibrium constant at 30°C. Do these equations hold?
$$0 \stackrel{?}{=} \Delta G^{\circ}+RT \ln K$$
$$K \stackrel{?}{=} e^\frac{-\Delta G^{\circ}}{RT}$$

I believe this is **illegal**, as it contradicts the fact that some equilibria are less favored at higher temperatures. However, I'm having trouble finding confirmation online, especially since the above equation has [no easily searchable name](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15365/what-is-the-name-for-the-equation-%CE%94g-%CE%94g-rt-ln-q).

Comment: Delta G is temperature dependent. See also [van't Hoff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation) : $\frac{\mathrm{d}(ln K)}{\mathrm{d}T} = \frac{\Delta_r H)}{RT^2}$ //  Try to learn more flexible searching, like `site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org equilibrium constant temperature dependance`   //
I am not aware of any law that forbids writing false equality statements, so it is probably legal, at least in most countries.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/127313/72973. In both cases, temperature is an explicit part of the mathematical relationship but other quantities in it are highly temperature-dependent as well.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, $K$ is itself temperature dependent. That is to say, $K = K(T)$ is a function of temperature, so

$$\Delta_\mathrm{r} G^\circ = -RT\ln K(T)$$

and the temperature dependence in $\Delta_\mathrm{r} G^\circ$ not only arises from the $RT$ term but also the $K$ term.

The dependence of $K$ on temperature is described by the van 't Hoff equation. I've [written about it here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32385/16683) (a while ago!).

$$\frac{\mathrm d(\ln{K})}{\mathrm dT} = \frac{\Delta_\mathrm{r} H^\circ}{RT^2}$$